# How to change name of OSX application in dock and app switcher?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, plist

I've toyed around with the Info.plist in my application (foo.app) and set the CFBundleName and CFBundleDisplayname to "bar", however OSX continues to render the name as "foo", so it seems to be using the app bundle name rather than the display name I specified in my plist.

Do I necessarily need to have this field set in the plist: LSHasLocalizedDisplayName? Because I do not particularly care about having the application name localized.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to rename projects in the info.plist, as this name is used elsewhere, too!

In XCode select the project from the top left corner, then in the Identity and Type section of the File inspector (on the right), enter a new name into the Name field. Press return. A dialog is displayed, listing the items in your project that can be renamed. The dialog includes a preview of how the items will appear after the change.

Source: http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/#/dev3db3afe4f

Comment: suppose for whatever reason that my project doesn't conform to tradtiaional xcode solutions, is there a way to achieve the desired effect? Also, when you say the name is used elsewhere too, where else?